# Custom order method API V1

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, soap-api-v1

I have ERP and connector, where I need to connect order with my magento order. For that I've created erp_order_id inside magento. And now I need to create custom API V1 method - setErpId (which will set ID from ERP to erp_order_id field in magento), since there only addComment, cancel, hold, etc.. Can anyone help? Never did this before..

Answer (score 1):

[Magento Order API](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/salesOrder.html) protects the order from being manipulated.

You are able to [Create your Own API](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html), and this is the RECOMMENDED approach for security reasons. The disadvantage in this approach is that you need to create and maintain code on both sides (Magento and ERP) in order to get the system to work. But once this custom API is setup, it should be pretty easy to maintain, at least on the Magento side.